# Floating Pop-up menu plus button to close button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to make the "+" button in the lower right corner (see screenshot) transform 45 degrees when clicked so the "+" becomes an "x" and then back to a "+" when the button is clicked again.  The modal operates the way I want it to, the button doesn't.  Here is the code and screenshots:

```css
.add-btn-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add-btn-container h1 {
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.add-btn {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #ff6b6b;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}

.add-btn:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./AddButton.css";

const AddButton = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="add-btn-container">
        <div>
          <h1 toggled={isOpen} toggle={setIsOpen} className="add-btn">
            +
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddButton;
```

[image: Modal Closed]

[image: Modal opened]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

1. You have to update toggle to onClick - there is no toggle handle https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html
2. Css you have to use rotate prop
3. for any changes happening for CSS need to know you need to provide class that way you can change the style
4. when toggle happens h2 won't get active better to use other class

```css
.add-btn-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add-btn-container h1 {
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.add-btn {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #ff6b6b;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.add-btn.close-btn {
  transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg);
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./AddButton.css";

const AddButton = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="add-btn-container">
        <div>
          <h1 toggled={isOpen} onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)} className={isOpen ? "add-btn close-btn" : "add-btn"}>
            +
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddButton;
```